# Fullscreen editors?

Tags: ide, editor, text-editor

Whilst fiddling recently with [Ulysses 2.0](http://www.the-soulmen.com/ulysses/index.html) - "The definitive creative writing package", I was struck by how effective the fullscreen/console mode was at focusing my mind on actually getting words on the page.

Are there any code editors that include a similar function? Or even a hack that allows code highlighting in Ulysees?

Preferably, for me, OSX, but feel free to list alternatives for others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any console based editor ([vim](http://www.vim.org/), [emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/), [nano](http://www.nano-editor.org/), ...) can be used in full screen mode, as long as the terminal in which it is run supports it. And I'd wager that most or all do. Usually this functionality is bound to **<kbd>F11</kbd>** or **<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>**.

Answer (score 3):

[MacVim](http://code.google.com/p/macvim/) has a fullscreen mode: `:set fullscreen`, `:help fullscreen`, and <kbd>⇧⌘F</kbd>.

Comment: Almost my chosen answer just for introducing me to Mac Vim :)

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio has a fullscreen mode via pressing <kbd>Shift+Alt+Enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

Notepad++ has fullscreen mode by pressing F11 (or f12 i can't decide).

Answer (score 1):

I use [Think](http://freeverse.com/mac/product/?id=7013) from Freeverse. It's a free utility that highlights your current app and simply darkens everything else, enabling you to focus on your document.

You can use it with your favorite editor. If you use Eclipse, you can double click the editor tab to maximize it, collapsing all other views. You can also customize the colors (if you prefer white text on dark background). It's not quite the same, but not bad.

Answer (score 0):

This is going to end up a long list!

I use Textpad as my text editor when not using Visual Studio - http://www.textpad.com - and it has a fullscreen mode.